# OSGi Equinox + Jetty - simple REST deploy using web.xml

Tags: java, rest, jetty, osgi, equinox

Trying a simple REST implementation on OSGi Equinox + Jetty - simple REST deploy using web.xml

Below are the details of my implementation:

Resource file:

```
@Path("jsonstatus")
public class JsonResource {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JsonResource.class);

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String listConferences() {
        logger.info("Returning the status");
        return "{\"status\": \"success\"}";
    }
}
```

Application Implementation:

```
public class JerseyApplication extends Application {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JerseyApplication.class.getName());
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        logger.info("--Returning all the claess-");
        Set<Class<?>> result = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        result.add(JsonResource.class);
        result.add(StatusResource.class);
        return result;
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SimpleREST</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>my.learnings.osgi.rest.jetty.activator.JerseyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SimpleREST</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

All the OSGi core, console and jetty jars are added: When I start the Equinox, i get the below error. I dont have the activator mapped to bundle when i deployed using web.xml

But with activator and web.xml removed, REST API works, No error during equinox startup.

Simple Activator:

```
@Override
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Starting the bundle");
    ServletContextHandler ch = new ServletContextHandler();
    ch.setContextPath("/");
    ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer());
    holder.setInitParameter("javax.ws.rs.Application", JerseyApplication.class.getName());
    ch.addServlet(holder, "/*");
    context.registerService(ContextHandler.class.getName(), ch, null);
}
```

When searched in the internet, i saw, need to configure JNDI, This is very basic simple REST which does not require a database. So got confused why we need JNDI. Some article discussed about initialization of the java.naming.factory.initial. But those are given for jboss. Not sure how to configure the initial context for jetty.All the combinations i tried are in the github code.

If you could help to get the initial context configured in the OSGi-jetty would really a great help. I am looking for a deployment with web.xml way of servlet creation on OSGi with jetty

Below repository contains the code which I tried:
https://github.com/pkolanda/my-learning-osgi-simple-rest-with-jetty
 to run the code, mvn clean install and run the run.sh shell script under the target/my-learning-osgi-simple-rest-with-jetty-0.1 folder.

Meanwhile i am looking into this post
Log:

```
11:14:33.951 [Start Level: Equinox Container: 6ee1939d-123f-4def-860f-dfc2e21bdfc4] WARN  o.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext - Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@7c19344a{/my-learning-osgi-simple-rest-with-jetty-1.0-SNAPSHOT,file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8081-my-learning-osgi-simple-rest-with-jetty-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar-_my-learning-osgi-simple-rest-with-jetty-1.0-SNAPSHOT-any-9046322855444487913.dir/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{file:/home/prakash/mygit/my-learning-osgi-simple-rest-with-jetty/target/my-learning-osgi-simple-rest-with-jetty-0.1/plugins/my-learning-osgi-simple-rest-with-jetty-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar}
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:350)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration.createEnvContext(EnvConfiguration.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration.preConfigure(EnvConfiguration.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.osgi.boot.BundleWebAppProvider.bundleAdded(BundleWebAppProvider.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.osgi.boot.BundleWebAppProvider$WebAppTracker.addingBundle(BundleWebAppProvider.java:80)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:475)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:229)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:911)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1783)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1763)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1725)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1656)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:343)
____________________________
Welcome to Apache Felix Gogo

g!
```

Comment: Any help would be really helpfull

Comment: Adding the below params to java process help solve the problem
-Djava.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.eclipse.jetty.jndi \
 -Djava.naming.factory.initial=org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.InitialContextFactory \